# Is it possible to configure a virtualbox machine as an internal server?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, routing

I need to be able to configure my virtualbox machine to be accessed from the host (my laptop) without the routing through the Internet. 
Right now I have a virtualbox machine with hostonly adapter `vboxnet0` and `NAT`. The virtual machine has a static IP address 192.168.56.50. I want all requests from the host to IP address 192.168.56.50 to be directed straight to the virtualbox machine (with the IP address 192.168.56.50). I can't use bridged interface because the Internet is limited on the host and not always persist.

Comment: You might want to look at this article - - https://2buntu.com/articles/1513/accessing-your-virtualbox-guest-from-your-host-os/

Comment: It doesn't work in my case. I think my routes are not configured properly on the host or virtualbox isn't configured properly

Comment: What is the IP address of the host?  From your post it sounds like both the host and VM have the same IP address.

Comment: The host has the IP 192.168.56.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't have a proper routing on the virtual machine.
My first interface (host-only) has a configuration:
*/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0*:

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
PROXY_METHOD="none"
BROWSER_ONLY="no"
BOOTPROTO="static"
DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE="stable-privacy"
NAME="eth0"
DEVICE="eth0"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPV6_PRIVACY="no"
IPADDR=192.168.56.50
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
PEERDNS=no
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
ZONE=public
```

My second interface (NAT) has a configuration:
*/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1*:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=eth1
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=yes
PEERDNS=no
```

So, my VM had the Internet, but I couldn't connect to the VM from the host. After that I tried to add `GATEWAY=192.168.56.1` to the `eth0` and it fixed the problem with the host (I could connect to the VM from the host) but I didn't have the Internet. That is why I removed `GATEWAY=192.168.56.1` from `eth0` and added a manual route for the host-only interface.
*/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0*:

```
192.168.56.0/24 via 192.168.56.1 dev eth0
```

After reboot, I could connect to the VM from the host and my VM had the Internet.